# pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available what to do with environments variables?

Tags: python, ssl, pip, environment-variables

I'm using Python 3.11.5. When I try to install modules using pip, I face this issue:

> WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL,
> however the ssl module in Python is not available. Could not fetch URL
> https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl
> certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't
> connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) -
> skipping WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of
> pip.

My environment variables are:

> C:\Users\Admin\Scripts C:\Users\Admin
> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher
> C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3 C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Library\bin
> C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Scripts
> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts
> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
> C:\Anaconda3 C:\Anaconda3\Scripts  C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin
> C:\Users\Admin\Scripts C:\Users\Admin
> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher
> C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3 C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Library\bin
> C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\Scripts
> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts
> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin

Comment: Have you tried anything to fix this? If so, please add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have some duplicate paths in your environment variables, try to remove those. (Not sure if that will make any difference, but it's definitely good practice.) Also make sure the paths are all correctly separated with a semicolon.

The [entry order or the paths matters](https://superuser.com/questions/1465493/why-does-path-entry-order-matter): Try putting the paths to your Python installations before the other paths to make sure they're resolved correctly.

If none of that helps, try uninstalling and reinstalling Python to get a clean and complete installation.